# Submitting resignation letter without getting job

Tags: resignation

Due to family reasons, I have submitted resignation letter to my current company. And I am currently serving notice period. When I am going for some interview, should I tell the truth regarding the reason for my resignation or not?

I have not got a job till now. Is it fine to reveal to a company that I am serving notice period without job?

Comment: Please clarify - are you taking time off from working for a family reason, or are you trying to immediately find another job?

Comment: How long is your notice period? How much time do you have left?

Comment: I am baffled. If you are resigning from your company for family reasons, then why are you available for interviews with other company? If you say to the company you are interviewing with that you resiged for "family reasons", the first question in your interviewers' mind is what are you doing interviewing with them. Unless you are proactive and specific with the interviewer about the "family reasons" enough that the interviewer is reassured that the "family reasons" don't apply to the company you are interviewing with, your interview is going to be a non-starter.

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan Relocating to be nearer an ailing relative. Quitting a job with unsociable hours so as to be able to handle childcare duties. Etc etc.

Comment: @PhilipKendall The OP has no real option but to be as specific to the "family reasons" as you are. If I were the interviewer and I got "relocating to be nearer an ailing relative", my follow up question would be "How does this affect your availability to put in a 40-hour week?" If the OP is the only available care giver for the ailing relative, that would be a red flag. And the OP has to answer the question with the knowledge that the OP is competing with other candidates who have no such issues.

Answer (score 1):

> is it fine to reveal to a company that I am serving notice period without job?

Any company that hires you will call your old company to do check on employment dates.  Unless you have a very long notice period (the average in the U.S. is 2 weeks), you will likely leave your job before you will be officially hired on.  **I would assume this fact will come to light at some point.**

The future employer will likely perceive leaving out that you're serving your notice period as a lie.  **Be Honest.**   Explain your family reason for leaving, don't leave your new boss to find out on his own.